# How to get the span of a dictionary as it appears on the site?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the meanings in the "noun" heading of the word the user enters.
This is my code for now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
word=raw_input("Enter word: ").lower()
        url=('http://www.dictionary.com/browse/'+word)
        r=requests.get(url)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
try:
    meaning=soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"def-content"}).get_text()
    print "Meaning of",word,"is: "
    print meaning
except AttributeError:
    print "Sorry, we were not able to find the word."
    pass
finally:
    print "Thank you for using our dictionary."
```

Now suppose the user enters the word "`today`" and my output will be:

> ```
>    this present day:                 Today is beautiful.
> ```

I dont understand why does it leave so many spaces and why doesnt the part

> "Today is beautiful"

come down.
Anyway when you look up that word on this [site](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/today?s=t), you can see there are 2 meanings yet my program only shows one.
I want the output to be:

```
1.this present day:
Today is beautiful.
2.
this present time or age:
the world of today.
```

Can anyone explain me whats wrong and how can i fix it?
I have no idea what's wrong so please dont think I dint try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the first noun meaning using the above code.
I have rewritten the code, it is as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

word = raw_input("Enter word: ").lower()
url = ('http://www.dictionary.com/browse/' + word)
r = requests.get(url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

nouns = bsObj.find("section", {"class": "def-pbk ce-spot"})

data = nouns.findAll('div', {'class': 'def-content'})
count = 1

for item in data:
    temp = ' '.join(item.get_text().strip().split())
    print str(count) + '. ' + temp
    count += 1
```

Explanation:

Yes. Assuming the website shows noun meaning first, I am retrieving the first section which contains complete noun data. Then I am finding all the meanings under that section inside data variable and iterating it in a loop and fetching the text of each meaning present in the data. Then to remove all the extra spaces I am splitting the fetched text and the joining it with a single space along with the addition of a number at the beginning

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain?

Comment: Instead of manually keeping track of `count` - use `enumerate()`.

Comment: @TarunGupta, make that (explanation) as the answer and not a comment. Might consider reading [How do I write a good answer?](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    meaning = soup.find(attrs={"class": "def-pbk ce-spot"}).get_text(separator="\n",strip=True)
```

### you can strip the whitesapce of the text by pass strip=True to get_text()

the reason way you don't got all the text is that you seletor is wrong, you should make the range bigger. 
I add separator= '\n' to get_text() to format output.
if you hava any question, you can read the BeautifulSoup Document.

Comment: That answers my one part of the question.The other was to get all the meaning of the word in noun form.