# Scraping visible text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am an absolute newbie in the field of web scraping and right now I want to extract visible text from a web page. I found a piece of code online :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/"
web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url , "lxml")
print (soup.prettify())
```

To the above code, I get the following result :

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:282: UserWarning: "http://www.espncricinfo.com/" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
  ' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   http://www.espncricinfo.com/
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Anyway I could get a more concrete result and what wrong is happening with the code. Sorry for being clueless.

Comment: Can you maybe read the error? We aren't here to regurgitate information in a slightly more readable format for you

Comment: also what do you mean by **extract visible text**, can you give an example of a website, and what kind of text you can extract.

Comment: Sorry! It's basically a user warning which states that I have supplied beautiful soup with a URL which I probably should use a HTTP client for. Beautiful soup would only accept the document behind the URL.

Comment: Now look at your code and see what might be causing that.

Comment: @RohinGopalakrishnan I eventually want to extract a Kannada paragraph from a particular news link (say Udayavaani).

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty try [reading my question and the answer by Tarun Gupta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480261/how-to-get-the-span-of-a-dictionary-as-it-appears-on-the-site/40480688#40480688)

Comment: what texts exactly you want to extract ??

Comment: @Ayoub;@RohinGopalakrishnan - I would like to extract the news paragraph from say the following link http://www.udayavani.com/kannada/news/bangalore-city-news/178364/hindus-do-not-care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the html document and not url to prettify to:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/"
web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page , 'html.parser')
print (soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I am getting an 'ascii' codec can't encode character error.

Comment: Just copy pasted this code both on mac and linux, got a response. Which line is giving you error?

Comment: Thanks! The above code runs if we explicitly encode the output given by the prettify function.

Comment: Are there any better tools to scrape and could you hint me to a process I could learn on how to scrape in a specific manner depending on what I need?

Comment: As far as encoding is concerned, from the doc https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings , you can specify encoding. As far as scraping is concerned, each case is separate, depending on the exact format, how complex the data is. Beautiful soup is pretty much it if you want to actually parse the html. In some cases, you can get by with a simple regex search

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "lxml")
```

you should pass a file-like object to BeautifulSoup,not url.

url is handled by `urllib2.urlopen(url)` and stored in `web_page`